# Inserting elements of vector into set, while printing set elements gets compilation issue c++98

Tags: c++, vector, stl, set, c++98

I am inserting vector values into set. After that i am trying to print set values where i get compilation issues. please help me to understand what i am doing wrong.

```
code:
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   set<string> s1;
   vector<string> v1;
   v1.push_back("Hello");
   v1.push_back("Hello");
   v1.push_back("Hi");
   v1.push_back("Hi");
   v1.push_back("Cya");

   for(int i=0; i<v1.size(); i++)
   {
      s1.insert(v1[i]);
   }

   for(int i= 0; i<s1.size(); i++)
   {
       cout<<s1[i]<<endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

```
compilation error:
 error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::set<std::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘int’)
        cout<<s1[i]<<endl;
```

Comment: you should consult some referece for `std::set`, eg https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set. You won't find `std::set::operator[]` there, because sets dont have that operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the iterator interface:

```cpp
for (std::set<std::string>::const_iterator it = s1.begin(), end = s1.end();
     it != end; ++it) {
  std::cout << *it << '\n';
}
```

You could also use `std::copy`:

```cpp
std::copy(s1.begin(), s1.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```